# Update user location with a button and draw a route swift

Tags: json, swift, google-maps, time, location

I have an application that draw a route between the user location and a marker. It´s working fine, but if the user changes its location and push on other marker, the route draw from first location.

This was logic. The function locationManager was stopping the updating location to save battery. This was the code:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    userLocation = locations[0]
    long = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    lat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    if let location = locations.first {

        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 14, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
        }
}
```

Then I create a button to update the user location and redraw the polyline:

```
@IBAction func ActualizarLocalizacion(sender: AnyObject) {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    originAddresslong = "\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
    originAddresslat = "\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"

    if markerLocation == nil
    {markerLocation = userLocation.coordinate
    }

     destinationAddresslong = "\(markerLocation.longitude)"
    destinationAddresslat = "\(markerLocation.latitude)"


    var directionsURLString = baseURLDirections + "origin=" + originAddresslat + "," + originAddresslong + "&destination=" + destinationAddresslat + "," + destinationAddresslong + "&key=MyKey"
    directionsURLString = directionsURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let directionsURL = NSURL(string: directionsURLString)


    Alamofire.request(.GET, directionsURL!, parameters: nil).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {

        case .Success(let data):

            var json = JSON(data)
            print(json)

            let errornum = json["error"]


            if (errornum == true){



            }else{

                //NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval (2)

                var routes = json["routes"].array

                if routes != nil{

                    var overViewPolyLine = routes![0]["overview_polyline"]["points"].string
                    print(overViewPolyLine)
                    if overViewPolyLine != nil{

                        if self.routePolyline != nil {
                            self.routePolyline.map = nil
                            self.routePolyline = nil
                        }


                        let path = GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: overViewPolyLine)
                        self.routePolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
                        self.routePolyline.strokeWidth = 5
                        self.routePolyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                        self.routePolyline.map = self.mapView
                        overViewPolyLine = nil
                        routes = nil
                        json = nil

                    }

                }
            }
        case .Failure(let error):

            print("Hubo un problema con el servidor de direcciones: \(error)")
        }

}
}
```

I then see that I must push the button 3 times(!!!) for a correct redraw. I have used the code

```
   locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval (2)
```

and then I only have to push 2 times, but I dont know why it is happening. I suspect that this must be a problem with time of process but I dont know how handle this.

The function that I use when the user tap a marker is the same (formulas and variables) and in this case it only need one push.

Thanks for all.

P.D:

These are my imports:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import SRKUtility
import SRKRequestManager
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
```

And this is my markerLocation variable:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool {

    markerLocation = marker.position;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Finally I have separated button and the redraw code, which has been introduced in the locationmanager. This is the final code:

1- locationmanager
     func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

```
    userLocation = locations[0]
    long = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    lat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;

    originAddresslong = "\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
    originAddresslat = "\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"

    if markerLocation == nil
    {markerLocation = userLocation.coordinate
    }

    destinationAddresslong = "\(markerLocation.longitude)"
    destinationAddresslat = "\(markerLocation.latitude)"



    var directionsURLString = baseURLDirections + "origin=" + originAddresslat + "," + originAddresslong + "&destination=" + destinationAddresslat + "," + destinationAddresslong + "&key=AIzaSyB4xO_8B0ZoA8lsAgRjqpqJjgWHbb5X3u0"
    directionsURLString = directionsURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let directionsURL = NSURL(string: directionsURLString)


    Alamofire.request(.GET, directionsURL!, parameters: nil).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {

        case .Success(let data):

            var json = JSON(data)
            print(json)

            let errornum = json["error"]


            if (errornum == true){



            }else{

                //NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval (2)

                var routes = json["routes"].array

                if routes != nil{

                    var overViewPolyLine = routes![0]["overview_polyline"]["points"].string
                    let distancia = routes![0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["text"].string
                    if overViewPolyLine != nil{

                        if self.routePolyline != nil {
                            self.routePolyline.map = nil
                            self.routePolyline = nil
                        }


                        let path = GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: overViewPolyLine)
                        self.routePolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
                        self.routePolyline.strokeWidth = 5
                        self.routePolyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                        self.routePolyline.map = self.mapView

                        self.DistanciaLabel.setTitle(distancia,forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                        overViewPolyLine = nil
                        routes = nil
                        json = nil

                    }

                }
            }
        case .Failure(let error):

            print("Hubo un problema con el servidor de direcciones: \(error)")
        }

    }

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    if let location = locations.first {
        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 14, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

    }

}
```

2- Button

```
    @IBAction func ActualizarLocalizacion(sender: AnyObject) {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()       
        }
```